# Пунктуация слова "может"

Tags: пунктуация

Заспорили мы с учителем начальных классов по поводу пунктуации слова "может" в данном стишке.
Надо ли выделять запятыми?

Пушистая лошадка,
А может бегемот,
А может просто ватка 
По небу плывет.

Разъясните, кто из нас прав!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В данном случае слово "может" является вводным, но оно не отделяется запятой от предшествующего союза, поскольку здесь вводное слово нельзя изъять или переставить. Поэтому правильно:
Пушистая лошадка,

А может, бегемот,

А может, просто ватка

По небу плывет.